# Особенности реализации WYSIWYG редактора (contenteditable, iframe, hidden textarea+events)

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

Я видел несколько реализаций визуальных редакторов, таких как TinyMCE и CodeMirror. Все могу разделить на 3 группы:

- **DIV c contenteditable=true** - кажется в готовых проектах не используется в чистом виде
- **iframe + body[contenteditable=true]** - Такой подход используется в TinyMCE, где редактор находится в iframe
- **hidden texarea + Events + обычный DIV** - такой подход используется в CodeMirror, как я понимаю он постоянно держит фокус на скрытом textarea и читает события перевода каретки, вставки и ввода данных, и добавляет их в обычный нередактируемый (contenteditable=false) блок. Причем даже выделение текста делается с помощью цветного DIV.

В связи с этим у меня стоит выбор, какую реализацию выбрать и в чем ее особенности.

На данный момент мне надо:

- Простое форматирование
- Кастомную каретку
- Адекватное копирование/вставку контента с сохранением форматирования
- Возможно эффект плавного появления текста при печати

Использовать готовые разработки не могу.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очень рекомендую к прочтению (на англ.): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162540/contenteditable-div-vs-iframe-in-making-a-rich-text-wysiwyg-editor (+ по ссылкам), мы во многом пересекаемся, но там пишут разработчики существующих редакторов.

## Разница между `iframe` vs `<div contenteditable>`

iframe более "тяжелый" (создается отдельный документ), и соответственно, более изолирован:

- В iframe не попадет ничего из внешнего документа (в частности, стили). Это позволяет вам реализовать WYSIWYG для более ограниченного набора функциональности, чем доступна в Web. Простейший пример - будет ли ваш код готов к тому, что произвольные куски редактируемого контента будут `display: hidden` из-за унаследованных стилей? Более сложный - как будет работать каретка и выделение с унаследованными `float`? Ну и т.д.
- Содержимое iframe не повлияет на внешний документ. Где-то приводился пример, что баг браузера приводил к вставке контента "мимо" contenteditable - с iframe это будет менее жесткий баг;
- Народ пишет про безопасность. Сам не разбирался детально, но предполагаю, что может быть связано с тем, что в дочернем фрейме можно запретить "случайное" выполнение левого вредительского кода через что-нибудь вроде [<iframe sandbox>](http://htmlbook.ru/html/iframe/sandbox).

## contenteditable vs не-contenteditable

Тут все просто: несмотря на все свои баги^H^H^H^Hособенности, contenteditable все-таки реализует огромную кучу функциональности, в т.ч. такой, о которой мы даже не задумываемся (IME какой-нибудь).

Соответственно, либо:

- Реализуем всю необходимую функциональность самостоятельно (это CodeMirror, [Ace](http://ace.c9.io/), ["новый" (в 2010) google docs](http://googledrive.blogspot.ru/2010/05/whats-different-about-new-google-docs.html)).

  - Это возможно, если у вас есть возможность потратить тысячи человеко-дней (Google) или необходимая функциональность существенно сужена (например, в CodeMirror и Ace редактируется только plain text - код);
  - Позволяет: иметь полный контроль над происходящим
- Используем contenteditable:

  - "Проще" в реализации (хотя см. ниже) - быстрее получается что-то работающее
  - Ограничения по функциональности, обходить которые будет все сложнее, если не невозможно совсем.

## Постановка задачи

Извиняюсь, если это бесполезное капитанство, но вы точно уверены про невозможность использования готовых наработок? Из формулировки вопроса неочевидно, что вы осознаете трудоемкость этого начинания.

- В связи с отсутствием нормальных API в браузерах, кучи багов, нехватки внятной документации и т.п., ваше начинание по сути сведется к реализации очень большого количества тривиального встроенного функционала методом длительных исследований и экспериментов.
- Если у вас опасения по поводу лицензий и запрещено смотреть в опенсорсные реализации WYSIWYG, то исследования еще больше усложняются.
- Лично у меня осознание пришло, когда я реализовал в чистом contenteditable одну операцию: дано `<li>text <b>te|xt</b></li>` (`|` - каретка), нужно реализовать то, что происходит при нажатии на Enter. С тремя допущениями и двумя TODO это занимает 20+ строк кода ...
- Самое прекрасное, что сама задача WYSIWYG весьма плодородная в плане багов. Вот тут про это хорошо написано: [Why ContentEditable is Terrible. Or: How the Medium Editor Works](https://medium.com/medium-eng/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480)