# Как изменить содержимое, скопированное пользователем?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Имеется следующий блок:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
     Здесь html код
</div>
```

Этот блок я могу редактировать прямо на странице, НО если он содержит HTML стилизованный текст, то при копировании этого текста вместе с ним копируется и соответствующий HTML код. Вопрос: как очистить буфер при копировании от HTML кода и оставить ТОЛЬКО текст? Заранее спасибо за ответ на столь нестандартный вопрос.

Comment: Зачем вам слой с `contenteditable="true"` и куда вы копируете фрагмент?

Comment: Слой мне нужен для простенького HTML редактора, ну а текст я копирую в другие такие же слои.

Comment: Если вы о проблеме когда копируете и вставляете в этот же div - то это проблема contenteditable - это не надежный способ делать редактор. Обычно есть скрытое текстовое поле, которое неявно перехватывает ввод и визуализирует это в элементе редактора.

Comment: Александр, именно об этой проблеме и идёт речь. А можно поподробнее о вами изложенном способе реализации аналога contenteditable?

Comment: Я задавал вопрос по этой теме, можно кое-что подчерпнуть от туда: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435684

Comment: Угу.. Спасибо. А вообще можно ли перехватить буфер и видоизменить его? Тогда contenteditable становится неплохой штукой для редактора на мой взгляд.

Comment: Можно перехватить событие копирования в буфер, и уже самому в буфер поставить что вам нужно. Как в буфер скопировать можно тут прочитать http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581345/click-button-copy-to-clipboard-using-jquery/30905277#30905277